# Adding javascript attributes to an anchor

Tags: javascript, onclick

i have search before but didnt find the exact case
i would like to add a javascript attribut to a href 
exemple:

```
<a href="http://site.com/">my site</a>
```

i need to add this attribut:

```
onclick="this.href='http://somesite.com'"
```

result

```
<a href="http://site.com/ onclick="this.href='http://somesite.com'">my site</a>
```

could you help me to process this please ?

thanks you very much

Comment: Is the result what you are getting, or what you need?

Comment: And if you want to use this specifically to override the link destination (for which I cannot come up with a non-hackish reason to be honest) why wouldn't you change the href attribute instead?

Comment: Why not just set the correct href to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

Before I begin, let me mention that inline javascript in not recommended and is frowned upon.

First, let me point out that you missed a `"` in your code:

```
<a href="http://site.com/ onclick="this.href='http://somesite.com'">my site</a>
------------------------^
                        "
Now, you should have this:

<a href="http://site.com/" onclick="this.href='http://somesite.com'">my site</a>
```

That should hopefully work.

Good luck.